# How call php variable in Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm converting my static Html website into wordpress and some images don't show. 
This is because I use Jquery to change the "src" of my image. 
now in my index.php I added bloginfo('template_url') in every image src. My problem is I don't know how to call it in Jquery.

In my php code it looks like this

```
  <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo-dark.png">
```

and

in my JS code I access it like this

```
$("img").attr("src","images/logo-light.png");
```

How do I call the  in JQuery? 
TYIA

Comment: Try `$("img").attr("src","<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>images/logo-light.png");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `wp_localize_script` which allows you to access php data in JavaScript file.

First register your script using `wp_enqueue_script`

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'theme_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/code.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
```

Then register your php variables to the code.js file.

```
$phpData = array(
    'logo_dark' => get_template_directory_uri()."/images/logo-dark.png",
);
wp_localize_script( 'theme_script', 'themeObj', $phpData );
```

Here

1. `theme_script` is the name of your javascript WordPress handle which
   we used on wp_enqueue_script.
2. `themeObj` is the name of JavaScript variable which we will use to
       access to our php data from JavaScript file.
3. `$phpData` is an array of the data we wish to serve.

Now  can access the logo_dark value using `themeObj.logo_dark` from your JS file.

```
$("img").attr("src", themeObj.logo_dark);
```

For more info, check [wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("img").attr("src","<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>images/logo-light.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

This may do this :

```
$("img").attr("src","<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo-light.png");
```

Comment: It displays <?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?> as a text

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your php function in jQuery block in your .php file then you can use the code which @vaibhav and @elraphty pointed out

```
$("img").attr("src","<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo-light.png");
```

And if you want to use it in .js file then you need to assign a variable in head tag

```
<script>
   var baseImgurl =  '<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>';
</script>
```

and then use it in .js file

```
$("img").attr("src",baseImgurl+"/images/logo-light.png");
```